# define a controller and use twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I want to user a controller for two separated div and when I do that , it send $http requests twice
How can i use the scope of other controllers?
here is my code :

```
            <div data-ng-controller="productCTRL">
                <span ng-model="basket | count"></span>
              ....Some HTML Code......
            </div>
            <div data-ng-controller="AuthController">
                   ....Some HTML Code...
            </div>
            <div data-ng-controller="productCTRL">
               <ul ng-repeat="product in products">
                  <li>{{product.title}}</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: You question is not clear, are you calling controller's function on some event?

Comment: i made that more clear

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to access the scope of other controllers-

Three are ways to communicate-

1. Parent child inherited scope - You have to create a parent controller and child controller can communicate using Parent scope. It is recommended only for tightly coupled controllers.
2. Event bus - Subscribe can listen on event ($on) and publisher can publish using $emit (current to parent scope can access using $on) or $brodcast (current to child scope can access using $on). Sibling controller can't share the data using this approach. To share the data between sibling controller, you can use $rootScope.broadcast and this event will be listen by all scope including sibling controllers. It is also coupled using event.
3. Using service - Both controller can share the data using common service because services are singleton.

Answer (score 2):

**One approach...**

You could use a monolithic controller:

```
<div data-ng-controller="mainCTRL">
    <div data-ng-controller="productCTRL">
        <span ng-model="basket | count"></span>
        ....Some HTML Code......
    </div>
    <div data-ng-controller="AuthController">
        ....Some HTML Code...
    </div>
    <div data-ng-controller="productCTRL">
       <ul ng-repeat="product in products">
          <li>{{product.title}}</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then if you make the `$http` call in `mainCTRL` instead of `productCTRL`, it will run just once when the view is rendered. You could then access the data held in `mainCTRL` from `productCTRL` via scope inheritance.

**Another approach...**

You could move the `$http` call to an angular service or factory. Since these are singletons, only one instance will ever exist and that means that only one `$http` call would be made when the app is first loaded. You would then store the returned data locally in the service and expose it publicly.

Here is a simple implementation as a factory:

```
app.factory("productService", function($http){

  var products = [];

  $http.get("api/products/get-products").then(function(response){
    products = response.data;
  });

  return {
    products: products
  }
});
```

If you inject the factory into your `productCTRL` it will have direct access to the `products` data:

```
appController("productCTRL", function(productService){
  $scope.products = productService.products;
});
```

The controller will still be instantiated twice, but it's only going to reassign the `$scope.products` variable. Most importantly, it no longer makes a redundant call over HTTP to your API.